# Javascript - A problem with the validation of my form

Tags: javascript, forms, email, email-validation

I have a problem with the validation script of my `php form` to send an email, and although it works very well to validate the form, when the user clicks on the **"accept"** button of the `alert`, **the script does not block the action, and the form is sent anyway**...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="form">
 <section>
  <form action="send.php" method="post" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
  <label for="email"></label>
  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" maxlength="50">
  <input type="hidden" name="privacy" value="blahblahblah"/>

  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" onclick="validate(this);">

  </div>
  </form>
 </section>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT (validation):**

```
function validate () {
    var email;
    email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    expresion = /\w+@\w+\.+\w/;

if(email === "") {
    alert("You cannot submit this request. You must give us an email");
    return false;
    }

else if (email.length>50) {
    alert("The maximum for email is 50 characters");
    return false;
    }

else if (!expresion.test(email)) {
    alert("Check your information. The email format is not valid");
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: alert will freeze the JS engine. Better include this in some kind of modal

Comment: @karthick But in other cases works perfectly for me, and using the native alert of the visitor's browser. Now I don't know why it doesn't work. Tested in Opera, Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the event to onsubmit and put it on the form.

```js
function validate () {
    var email;
    email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    expresion = /\w+@\w+\.+\w/;

if(email === "") {
    alert("You cannot submit this request. You must give us an email");
    return false;
    }

else if (email.length>50) {
    alert("The maximum for email is 50 characters");
    return false;
    }

else if (!expresion.test(email)) {
    alert("Check your information. The email format is not valid");
    return false;
    }
  console.log('passed!');
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
    <section>
        <form action="" method="post" accept-charset='UTF-8' onsubmit="return validate(this);">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" maxlength="50">
            <input type="hidden" name="privacy" value="blahblahblah"/>

            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND">
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```